# Android - Camera, save pic every 20 seconds

Tags: android, camera, preview

If it possible to retrieve camera pic in background and save the pic every 30 seconds?
Does anyone have example? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking about is partially possible.  I'm going to break your question into a couple parts to answer:

1. Is it possible to retrieve a camera pic in the background? NO
2. Is it possible to save a pic every 30 seconds? YES

Basically, you can only open the camera and obtain preview frames to save if the `Camera` object is attached to a valid `SurfaceHolder` to draw with.  While this doesn't **technically** mean that the surface has to be **VISIBLE** (i.e. you can draw camera preview frames into a `SurfaceView` that is invisible, I believe), it does mean that there must be a valid surface in a running foreground Activity.

If you can live with this, though, you can easily write an application the auto-captures the preview frames every so often with the combination of the `Camera.PreviewCallback` and a `Handler` calling `postDelayed()` to tell the application when it's time to capture the next frame.  For an example, I'm going to point you at the [SDK Guide for Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture), since they provide all the information necessary to access a `Camera` instance and register for previews.

HTH

Comment: What about start app with showing the camera pic and if user want to move it background? I have such an app like iPWebCam and when you start app you can see camera pic, but you can also move to background. How it works? Camera pic still working but in service?

Comment: Also take note of the alert that app presents when going into background: `Note that not all phones support this: for some...it's required to have a surface where the video is drawn.`  There may be devices that let you open the camera with a valid surface and then don't crash if you take it away, but it will not be a universal solution supported by the Android platform, just hacks found in individual implementations.